# Why in the assumption of Markov inequality, $X$ is assumed to be a non-negative random variable?

Tags: probability, inequality

In the proof showing Markov inequality, 
$$P[X \geq a] \leq \dfrac{E[X]}{a}$$

I don't see why $X$ has to be a non-negative random variable

Going through the proof, the only restriction seems to be that $E[X] \leq a$, so that the left hand side is well-defined.

Wouldn't the expectation of $X$ be non-negative for selected random variables that takes on negative values?

Comment: What happens if $E[X] = -1$, $a=1$?

Comment: @Michael The OP's point is that there might be cases where the expectation is nonnegative even if the random variable is not nonnegative.

Comment: @angryavian Well the third paragraph says "the only restriction seems to be that $E[X]\leq a$".  But if you strengthen to assume "$0 \leq E[X] \leq a$," then consider $X \in \{-1,1\}$, $P[X=-1]=P[X=1]=1/2$, $a=1$.  So then $0= E[X]\leq a$. But $\frac{E[X]}{a}=0$ does not upper-bound $1/2$.

Comment: @Michael Yes, that looks like a good counterexample for OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$E[X] = E[X 1_{X \ge a}] + E[X 1_{X < a}] \ge a P(X \ge a) + 0 = a P(X \ge 0).$$

The nonnegativity of $X$ is used to assert $E[X 1_{X < a}] \ge 0$.